# strange ruby syntax for rails devise helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I saw the following code in deviser_helper.rb. What does <<-HTML ... HTML mean here:

```
html = <<-HTML
<div id="error_explanation" class="alert">
  <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
  <ul>#{messages}</ul>
</div>
HTML
```

Surely a great way to write embedded HTML code in ruby. But why this works and where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a [multiline string in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc).  Usually it's called a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) or here document.  From the linked documentation:

> Following a << you can specify a string or an identifier to terminate the string literal, and all lines following the current line up to the terminator are the value of the string.

The `-` after `<<` means that you can indent the terminator, so that the `HTML` at the end can have spaces or tabs before it.

Comment: Also, to reiterate, the fact that it's "HTML" here is not important -- it works just as well with FILE, EOF, TEXT, etc.  Also, you can continue coding on the same line as the start of the heredoc, e.g.

html = <<HTML.strip
blah
HtML